# Fill Excel Table with VBA Field by Field

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

I have an Excel table, that I need to fill record by record.

I began a code

```
Private Sub AddRecBro_Click()
    Dim Tbl As ListObject
    Dim NewRow As ListRow

    Set Tbl = Worksheets("Broker").ListObjects("Broker")
    Set NewRow = Tbl.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)

    ....

End Sub
```

Now I would like to populate this table field by field a bit like this...

```
Field("ID")=Max(Broker[ID])+1
Field("F1")=Sheets("Dashboard").Range("U5").Value
Field("F2")=Sheets("Dashboard").Range("U6").Value
Field("F3")=Sheets("Dashboard").Range("U7").Value
etccc
```

I don't know how to populate my list objects this way...Actually I have my data in column and not at the same place... so i would like to select them at their location to Fill up the New record...
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ListObject` table is comprised of a `HeaderRowRange` (if the table has headers) and a `DataBodyRange`. Both are `Range` objects that you can iterate using normal iteration methods for cells:

```
Dim r as Long, c as Long

For r = 1 to Tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
    For c = 1 to Tbl.DataBodyRange.COlumns.Count
        Tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(r, c).Value = "__Insert some value__"
    Next
Next
```

Comment: thks for your answer.. i have an error using `Tbl.DataBodyRange.cells(r, 1).Value = Max(Tbl.DataBodyRange.Column("A")) + 1`... do you know why?

Comment: What is the error? Perhaps try `= Application.Max(Tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(1)) + 1`.